# Am I allowed to ask other users to work with me on a software project?

Tags: support, etiquette, users

Am I allowed to ask for help from someone with an app that I'd like to start developing?
I want to get Swift or Object-C codes for the app that I am developing and I don't think I can manage to do that myself.

Comment: Check the profile of the top users in your tag of choice.  There are several users (no, I'm not one of them) who stuff something in their profile along the lines of, "If you wish to pay me for assistance with technology X, please feel free to contact me at [contact link]." As an added bonus, [contact link] often includes other people you can pay for help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No - please don't solicit requests for help Stack Overflow for your personal projects.  The community is willing to help you with a specific problem, but asking for another coder on your pet projects wouldn't be considered a constructive question.

If you have a specific question about something that you're developing, then feel encouraged to ask.  Asking for just code is usually frowned upon.

Comment: Would it be acceptable in the chat rooms? I haven't used them, but I get the impression that the range of what can be discussed may be much less restricted there.

Comment: I don't know that - I'm not a regular denizen of chat.  There are certainly more flexible topics permitted there, but I'm not sure how well someone asking someone else to help them join a project would be received.